# application_name is not available in audit logs in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, audit, auditing, audit-logging, sql-server-2017

I am looking for a way to fetch client application name in audit logs in SQL Server. As per the MSDN page, it should be available from SQL Server 2017 on-wards.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql

I have created a database level audit specification for select and insert and I want to determine which application is executing those queries.

Any help around this topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e038971-8bb5-45fb-8eca-5697fa24a857/applicationname-is-not-available-in-audit-logs-in-sql-server-2017?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Apparently you can only fetch that data using T-SQL at the moment. SSMS log viewer does not show those additional columns.